# How to add icon next to tile in UINavigationController title?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I'm trying to add a drop down arrow or an icon next to the title of navigation bar (shown in screenshot below) but haven't found a good solution, I thought it would be fairly straight forward but I just can't get a good solution going.

One approach I tried is to replace the title with a `UIButton` by setting the view controller's `navigationItem.titleView` but the problem with this approach is since my title can vary in length I can't the button frame size calculated the `CGRect` is reported as 0,0. If I try to update the button's frame in `viewWillDisplay()` method then the button frame change is zoomed in animated in place and it's visible to the user and quite a jarring effect.

Are there any other possible solutions, I feel like I'm just approaching this all wrong, it shouldn't be this hard.

[image: Nav bar with arrow]

Comment: http://www.onedollarapp.com/2010/10/17/using-a-single-button-in-titleview-of-uinavigationbar/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set a label with attributedstring,it will auto resize

Short title

[image]

Long title

[image]

For example

```
UILabel * label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,100, 40)];
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
label.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
NSTextAttachment * attach = [[NSTextAttachment alloc] init];
attach.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"memoAccess"];
attach.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20);
NSAttributedString * imageStr = [NSAttributedString attributedStringWithAttachment:attach];
NSMutableAttributedString * mutableAttriStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Title"];
[mutableAttriStr appendAttributedString:imageStr];
label.attributedText = mutableAttriStr;
self.navigationItem.titleView = label;
```

Comment: Do you know If it's possible to animate icon image changes for example by setting CATransform3DMakeRotation etc ? I want the tap gesture on the label to rotate the down chevron to up chevron.

Comment: how did you find out the label frame rect of 0,0,100,40 ? What if you don't know the size?

Answer (score 9):

If your character available as Unicode character in the list then you can add it to the string

Press : Ctrl + Command + Space

[image]

Suppose your character is DOWN ARROWHEAD then you can add it to your title string.

If you want to add the Attributed String or Icon then you can follow [Leo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3940672/leo)'s Answer.

Comment: Cool, this is nice easy solution provided the unicode characters align nicely with your label's font. I tried this earlier but didn't like unicode icons.

Answer (score 0):

Create a UIView contain UILabel and UIButton.

```
UIView * container = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
container.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

// title text
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 40)];
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
label.text = @"hello world";
label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByClipping;
label.numberOfLines = 1;
[label sizeToFit];

// button
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
button.frame = CGRectMake(label.frame.origin.x, label.frame.size.width, 20, 40);

// resize container
container.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, label.frame.size.width + button.frame.size.width, 40);

[container addSubview:label];
[container addSubview:button];

self.navigationItem.titleView = container;
```

Comment: This does not work because label.frame.size will be 0,0 until viewWillDisplay()